# how can i install ubuntu on my MacBook (15-inch, 2017)?

Tags: macbook

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)

This is my MacBook ,i can't use keyboard when i install ubuntu

In fact , i can't use wifi either

Only Ubuntu Live USB can boot normally, but the keyboard and touchpad are completely unusable, so nothing can be done except shutting down. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It will take [a lot of work](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux#keyboard--touchpad) to get all of the components on Apple's notebook to work with Linux. The company goes to great efforts to ensure that only macOS runs on their more recent notebooks.

Comment: Not ideal but you can also install it inside Mac OS using virtualization. Just don't use Mac and give your virtual OS all resources. "How can I solve this problem?" throw it away? Or sell it :D A system from 2017 that does allow Ubuntu is going to cost about 200 euro/dollars. That might be an option